# ES Must match filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this fairly simple es query and filter, using ES 2.3.5:

```
{
   "query": {
      "multi_match": {
         "query": "image",
         "fields": [
            "ToRecipients"
            "From",
            "Subject"
         ]
      }
   },
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "match": {
                  "ToRecipients": "johndoe"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "sort": [
      {
         "DateTimeSent": {
            "order": "desc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

For some reason it is not filtering by the `ToRecipients` field. The results coming back have all kinds of values for the field not just `johndoe`.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "image",
            "fields": [
              "ToRecipients",
              "From",
              "Subject"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "ToRecipients": "johndoe"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "DateTimeSent": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: oh so putting the filter in the bool then?

Comment: didn't make any difference

Comment: Run each sub-query separately and see it those match anything.

Comment: well weirdly, we tried the original query again and it worked... I don't know if the fact that the `ToRecipients` is an email and es treats them weirdly